# How to define a number in an if statement?

Tags: python

I ran into a problem while I was trying to make an if statement.

Below is my code so far:

```
while True:
    try:
        Names = int(input("Number of names: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You didn't put in a number, Try again.")
    finally:
        if Names == #this is where I'm stuck
```

Is there any way to define an integer, so that the loop breaks when the user puts in a number instead of a string?

Answer (score 0):

```py
while True:
    try:
        Names = int(input("Number of names: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You didn't put in a number, Try again.")
    else:
        break

# use Names here after the while loop, e.g:
for _ in range(Names):
    name = input("...")
```

`else` is not really necessary in this case, this is also fine:

```
while True:
    try:
        Names = int(input("Number of names: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("You didn't put in a number, Try again.")

    break
```

As is the other answer by bilke, although it's generally good to reduce the amount of code inside the `try` block so it's clearer where the exceptions you're handling might come from.

Answer (score 0):

So close to finding it out on your own! :D

```
while True:
    try:
        names = int(input("Number of names: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You didn't put in a number, Try again.")
```